# developin web app using .net need Info about Local System

Tags: c#

we are devoloping a web application using c#.net,ASP.Net 3.5,in that we need to know the infomation  of local system  like what are the  installed printers? is there any way to get the data using any scripting Languages? Plz let me know if any body knows the answer.

Thanks in advance
Prasad

Answer (score 1):

> we are devoloping a web application using c#.net,ASP.Net 3.5,in that we need to know the
>   infomation  of local system like what are the installed printers?

Are you? Why do you formulate this as a question. Are you not sure what you are doing?

> is there any way to get the data using any scripting Languages?

Maybe, maybe not. Irrelevant, though, as ASP.NET is not using scripting langauges on the server anyway. Your server sidel ogic will be ni C# or VB.NET likely (or any other .NET langauge) and by all means this is not a scripting langauge.

if yuo talk of the client side (i.e. from the browser: no way, and you have no busienss knowing. The internet is not a friendly place. Whatever rights you think you want can be abused by some bad person. And will be.

> Plz let me know if any body knows the answer.

Yes, someone knows the answer. Which answers yoru question. Note: you did not ask for an answer, you asked whether anyone knows the answer.

Now, real:

Yes, you can. WMI is your friend. The main problem will be:

- Understanding the WMI documentation. WMI is the Windows Management Instrumentation and you can prettya much see everything of any computer you can connect WMI to there.
- Configuring IIS to allow you local access.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that will help:

[How To Get Hardware Information (CPU ID, MainBoard Info, Hard Disk Serial, System Information , ...)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/GetHardwareInformation.aspx)